# Read static content from within the code of an application

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is there a way to read the contents of a static data directory or interact with that data in any way from within the code of an application?

Edit: Please excuse me if it wasn't clear at first, I mean getting a list of the files in that directory, not reading the data in them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Files marked as static in app.yaml are not available to your application; they're served from separate servers.

If you just need to list them, you could build a list as part of your deploy process.  If you need to actually read them, you'll need to include a second copy in your application directory (although the "copy" can be just a symlink; appcfg.py will follow symlinks and upload them.)

Comment: Yep, I've got the feeling this is the sad truth of the static data.

Answer (score 1):

You can just `open` them (only read only).